# Override webform confirmation and email message if token data is missing

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a webform in which I am using tokens to display data in the form submission confirmation and in a sent email.

Some of this data is pulled from a web service, and sometimes no data is returned by the API. This can result in the confirmation and email not being populated with data.

Form submission confirmation:

```
REPORT COMPLETE
Thank you for your report, which will be forwarded to: .
If you need to contact us about your report, you can do so at:
A confirmation email has been sent to: someone@example.com.
```

Email:

```
Thank you for reporting a problem at: Acme Inc.
Your report has been forwarded to .
Please do not reply to this email.
```

In this event, I'd like to override the confirmation and email message with a different message (that does not rely on data being available).

What is the best way to achieve this? Use `hook_form_alter` to test for missing values and then override the webform's `#confirmation` element? And how to override the email message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Settings handler allows you conditionally override the confirmation message and any other webform setting.

[image]

The Email handler support conditional logic and now also supports custom Twig template which allows you to use if/then (conditional) logic in the email message.

[image]

Comment: My confirmation message is defined at _admin/structure/webform/manage/my_webform/settings/confirmation_. This is not a handler, correct? Are you saying I need to define my confirmation message as a handler instead? I'm using _8.x-5.0-beta24_.

Comment: The latest RC of the Webform module supports both of the above features.  You would still need to define your default confirmation type & message, then you would use the 'Settings' handler to conditionally override it.  

BTW, I will be tagging the next RC this week.