# How can you prevent a Webform from going to a confirmation modal if remote post handler fails in a service response?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a webform with a single handler - an extended remote post handler that sends the submission to an external service. The entire form loads in a modal dialog and has two wizard steps.

This service can return a 200 (with confirmation id and date) or 400 (and any number of errors).

How can I either:

- Prevent the submission on error from the service, and reload the form to try again (with values retained)
- Change the confirmation message to reflect that something went wrong, and either reload the form fresh with that appended or just have a link in the modal that goes "back to form"

I have looked at a few other questions like:

- [Trigger redirect after Webform Remote Post Handler posted successfully](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263070/trigger-redirect-after-webform-remote-post-handler-posted-successfully)
- [How do I pass a response from a Webform custom handler back to Drupal to display on the confirmation page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282428/how-do-i-pass-a-response-from-a-webform-custom-handler-back-to-drupal-to-display)
- [Override webform confirmation and email message if token data is missing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254652/override-webform-confirmation-and-email-message-if-token-data-is-missing)

I can't get them to work. `preprocessConfirmation()` is never triggered in my handler, I don't see other examples or where that would be called. How are we supposed to implement that effectively? If there was an error saving the data to the remote service, I either want the user to try again, or just delete the webform submission in Drupal and start over.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is too late to halt the Webform with validation errors once it is past the validation phase ie. in `postSave()`. If you are expecting validation errors on user input however, then you could move the service call to **`WebformHandlerBase::validateForm()`** and then save the service response in the `$form_state` object if you need it.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state, $webform_submission);

    try {
      $response = $this->doServiceRequest()
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('foo', $e->getMessage());
      return;
    }

    // Save service response output.
    $webform_submission->setData($response->getData() + $webform_submission->getData());
  }
```

**Note:** This probably goes against the design of the `RemotePostWebformHandler`, but I think it could work..., or you could directly extend `WebformHandlerBase` instead.